# How do I create a restful api on top of a resource that has different methods to return different results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, routes

I have this resource

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   # lists all the system-level roles
  def Role.system_roles
    Role.find_all_by_system(true, :order => 'name')
  end

  # lists all the project-level roles
  def Role.project_roles
    Role.find_all_by_system(false, :order => 'name')
  end

  # lists all roles that can be used for workflow enforcement
  def Role.filter_roles
    not_for_filters = ['admin', 'manager']
    Role.project_roles.reject{|role| not_for_filters.include? role.name}
  end
end
```

Now REST API standards say you must return the resource this way

```
/roles
```

that is it.

Well in the index method of the controller I was doing this only

```
module Api::V1::Setup
  class RolesController < ApplicationController
    include ApiHelper

    layout nil

    def index
      system_roles_data = Role.system_roles
      render :json => roles_data, :status => :ok
    end
  end
end
```

I see other posts that suggest, well, pass in a parameter. I do not want to do that. Can  the following be supported?

```
/roles/system_roles
/roles/project_roles
```

What should be in the routes file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the corresponding methods in your `roles_controller.rb` (`system_roles` and `project_roles`), you could have something like this:

```
resources :roles do
  collection do
    get 'system_roles'
    get 'project_roles'
  end
end
```

The `system_roles` controller method would return `Role.system_roles` and `project_roles` would return `Role.project_roles`, respectively.

Comment: I am doing this in rails3. and I get this error. `undefined local variable or method `on' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fbf2deb8838>`. I think what you suggested is in rails4.  Unfortunately, cannot move to rails4. What I am missing